# Count how many times a function is called

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I was wondering if it's possible to count how many times a function is called and do something when it has been called 5 times for exemple. (and then it's restarting to count at 0).

If we take an exemple, what would it be ?

Somethink like :

```
movieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionExemple, false, 0, true);

function functionExemple(e:MouseEvent):void{
//do something;
count 1;
if (count = 5){
doThat();
count = 0;
}
```

So the function doThat would be called every 5 times.

I know the code is wrong. It's just in order to explain as good as possible what I meant.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: If you're wanting to do some optimization, get Adobe Scout.  Otherwise, follow null.point3r's suggestion.  Your concept is a valid approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some errors in your example.

```
var count:int=0; //variable declaration
function functionExemple(e:MouseEvent):void{
   //do something;
   count++;//<=>count 1;
   if (count == 5){//<=>if (count = 5){
      doThat();
      count = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess would be to set a global variable that acts as a counter then when the function is called - increment its value. When value hits 5 take action. I would also guess using some form of "getter" to get the counter value would also help. This is my initial stab at it.

Comment: Hmm do you have an exemple with codes ? (it's more visuable for me..)

Comment: You could use a global class with public fields.